# Cant add tabs into a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs, fragmentmanager

I am trying to build and Activity containing 2 fragments.I have already build one of them but I want the other one to have tabs in it.The problem is that i get an error on tabHost.addTab();

here is my Fragment

```
public class StatisticsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

Context mContext;
FragmentTabHost tabHost;
View rootView;
public StatisticsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statistics, container, false);

    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
Intent purposeIntent = new Intent(mContext, PurposeTab.class);
    FragmentTabHost.TabSpec tabPurpose = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Purpose")
            .setIndicator("Purpose")
            .setContent(purposeIntent);

    Intent priorityIntent = new Intent(mContext, PriorityTab.class);
    FragmentTabHost.TabSpec tabPriority = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Priority")
            .setIndicator("Priority")
            .setContent(priorityIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(tabPurpose);
    tabHost.addTab(tabPriority);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    return rootView;
}
```

and here is my Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StatisticsFragment fragmentStatistics = new StatisticsFragment();
    MainPageButtonsFragment fragmentMain = new MainPageButtonsFragment();


    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_statistics, fragmentStatistics, "Statistics").commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_page_buttons_fragment, fragmentMain, "Buttons").commit();
}
```

this is my LogCat which indicates that my error is on addTab and even suggest that i may forgot the "setup method" but I am not!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?

10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:692)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at .StatisticsFragment.onCreateView(StatisticsFragment.java:64)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:511)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
10-06 12:03:56.967 4033-4033/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
```

Comment: for tabs you can refer this http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, in my opinion, to add tabs to anything(Activity, Fragment), is using TabLayout from Google Design support library.

In your layout file, add TabLayout and ViewPager:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
--------------------------------------
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your Fragment/Activity file connect them by calling          `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);`

You should also override your getPageTitle method in ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    private String mTabTitles[] = new String[]{"Tab 1", "Tab 2"};

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int num) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return mTabTitles[position];
    }
}
```